# PayPal - Account management

Tags: paypal, management, money

I'm running an app that gets small donations (*Micro payments* up to ~11 USD) and also I'm doing some freelancing where I get some higher payments over PayPal too. (~900 USD a month)

Is it possible to have 2 accounts on PayPal?

(I'm asking because if someone send me money for my freelancing, they get the contact information from the app - Like info@app-example.com instead of info@freelancing-example.com )

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using manager.paypal, I believe you can set up users, and those users can be customized for different receipts.